# Heating ham/cooking hashbrown potato casserole in same oven

Tags: ham, casserole

I have to heat my spiral sliced ham at 275 for 2 hours. My hashbrown potato casserole needs to cook for 45 minutes at 350. I only have 1 oven--what is the best way to cook these 2 items so they are ready to eat at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do.

Wait until the ham has 30 minutes left, then move it to the bottom shelf, put the hash browns on the top shelf, baste the ham well and set the oven for 350. Pull the ham out after 30 minutes so it has time to rest, and leave the hash browns in until they are done.